# Why doesn't Meteor resolve SCSS imports?

Tags: meteor, sass

I have two files in `client` folder: `style.scss` and `staff.scss`. In the former, I import the latter:

```
//...
$spacing-unit: 1em;
//...
@import "./staff.scss"
```

and in `staff.scss` I try to use a variable that has been defined in `style.scss`:

```
//...
.staff {
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit;
}
```

but I'm having a following error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building the application:
   /Users/rishatmuhametshin/dev/smth/client/staff.scss:3:14: Scss
   compiler error: Undefined variable: "$spacing-unit".


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

which makes me think that Meteor ignored the import.

What should I do then?

Comment: The matter of my question is SCSS and variables within styles. If I'm correct with that, it has nothing to do with JS scoping (otherwise, I would already have happily known the solution).

Comment: No but it would have a lot to do with Meteor's files load order which is why I suggested to read this question since, even if it's on a different topic, it might provide the answer (in that case `style.scss` being loaded _after_ `staff.scss`).